# How to figure how many whistles to put in a pressure cooker?

Tags: indian-cuisine, pressure-cooker

Being from nepal where pressure cookers are the norms, it is tough for me to determine if something has been cooked "properly" or not.

Mainly, I cook rice, beans (peas etc) and cereals.

How many whistles do I wait? And with what does it depend?

Because of my lack of information, these things happen a lot:

- Rice isn't cooked.
- Rice is cooked but water is still there.
- Water in beans get decreased and it becomes salty.
- Beans are not cooked properly and is hard.

etc. Can you provide me a way of roughly estimating the number of whistles?

Comment: Namaste!  Welcome to SA.  As it happens, you question has already been answered here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54554/7180  Read that for details, but the short answer is don't count whistles, use a timer.

Comment: Once you have figured out the timing of your specific cooker, you’ll want to do a bit of troubleshooting on the  ratios, because only the first and last bullet point are fixed by cooking time. The others depend on ratios, the second means you are adding too much water, the third means either too little water and/or too much salt.